# Firefox for partial postback always timeout after 5 mins

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox

I just find weird bug in firefox 4.

I use partial postback on my web app.
and I use firefox 4 to test it.

Unfortunately every 5 mins, if I leave the browser un touch, and I came back again, and click my partial postback trigger, It will result timeout.

But It fine to other browser on the same computer.

Do you know what may cause the problem ?

THanks

Comment: As an interesting sidenote: chrome has a similar site timeout issue where if you leave it open untouched for too long then it refuses to make a callback to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of find the solution for it.

after checking if it is firefox and idle for 2 mins,
I call sync ajax call to other blank pages. then it will work